# Access Remote Maven Artifactory from Bitbucket Pipelines

Tags: maven, bitbucket-pipelines, bitbucket-cloud

I'm trying to set Bitbucket pipelines to run Maven `verify` command. What I currently struggle with is how to access dependencies that are defined in my POM. I have those dependencies in a remote artifactory but how do I set `settings.xml` on the BB pipelines?

I know that one way would be to have a `settings.xml` file in the root of my BB repository and use it in the `bitbucket-pipelines.yml` file - this works but I'm looking for a cleaner solution...

perhaps having the `settings.xml` embedded in a custom Docker image that is used in the yml file??

Any idea?

Comment: see: https://blog.abakri.xyz/configuring-settings-xml-in-bitbucket-pipeline/

Answer (score 0):

I believe the best practice would be to create a custom Docker image and copy the local settings.xml into the global settings directory (e.g: `/usr/share/maven/conf`), then publish the image and and use this image in the `bitbucket-pipelines.yml` script.